# Bind click and change checkbox angular2

Tags: javascript, checkbox, angular

I have a strange problem with checkboxes using angular2 (beta 17).

I'm trying to set same checkboxes as elements has the array and bind the change or click event.

For example I have an array:

```
myObjects=[
    {value:true},
    {value:true},
    {value:false},
    {value:true}
];
```

And I'm using the ngFor to create all the checkboxes:

```
<div *ngFor="let myObject of myObjects; let i = index" >
    <input 
            type="checkbox" 
            [checked]="myObject.value" 
            (change)="updateCheckedOptions(i, $event)"
    />
</div>
```

And finally I have a function in my component:

```
@Input() myObjects;

updateCheckedOptions(index,event){
    this.myObjects[index].value=event.target.checked;
}
```

But the problem is that the checkbox don't change, I mean that when I click the checkbox, if the initial state is checked, always remain checked and vice versa.

I have tried using (click), (change), [(ngModel)] but it does not work any.

Thanks!

Comment: I just copied and pasted your code in a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SjIRhAwa56ScfrJDZml3?p=preview), it's working fine. Although I think `object` is a reserved word.

Comment: Correction, I just checked, `object` is not a reserved word. It just didn't feel right :)

Comment: Hi, the objects name are only a symbolic name, I have edited the question with other name and I have added the type of the "myObjects" variable.

Thanks!

Comment: The name is not the issue, I was mistaken. Also, your code is working fine. Did you check the plunker on my commit ? There is probably some other code you didn't put in your question that's causing the problem.

Comment: I have found the problema, but my solution is only a workaround to continue the development.
I had to use the ngOnInit method to copy in a private attribute in my class the myObject input like: ngOnInit(){this.myPrivateMyObject=this.myObject} and use the myPrivateObject instead myObject and then works properly. I'm going to read more documentations but is a solution. Regards and thanks so much!

Comment: Please take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37077707/launch-an-event-when-checking-a-checkbox-in-angular2

Answer (score 1):

You can check ngModelChange:

```js
//This is your component

@Input() myObjects;

myObjects=[
    {value:true},
    {value:true},
    {value:false},
    {value:true}
];

updateCheckedOptions(index,event){
    this.myObjects[index].value=event.target.checked;
    console.log(index + " ---- " + event);
}
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let myObject of myObjects; let i = index" >
    <input 
            type="checkbox" 
            [checked]="myObject.value" 
            (ngModelChange)="updateCheckedOptions(i, $event)"
    />
</div>
```

Comment: Garbzade this is not working with angular 4 material and native html radio check box also.  below is my code                                                                         {{<input type = "checkbox" [checked]= "parentchecked" (ngModelChange)="listcheckboxchecked(list,$event)">{{list.value}}
  <mat-checkbox class="example-margin" [checked]= "parentchecked" (ngModelChange)="listcheckboxchecked(list,$event)">{{list.value}}</mat-checkbox><br>