# Launch an event when checking a checkbox in Angular2

Tags: html, checkbox, data-binding, typescript, angular

I'm newbie in Angular2 and in web globally , I want to launch an action that changes an oject paramater value in the Database when checking a `checkbox` and or unchecking it using `Material-Design`, I tried with `[(ngModel)]` but nothing happened. the idea is that i have to add some propositions with `checked | unchecked` status to tell if it is a `true` or `false` proposition. Here is the proposition model

```
export class PropositionModel {
    id:string;
    wordingP:string; // the proposition
    propStatus:Boolean; // the proposition status
}
```

here is the Html code for a proposition :

```
<div class="uk-width-xlarge-1-1 uk-width-medium-1-2">
                <div (submit)="addProp1()" class="uk-input-group">
                    <span class="uk-input-group-addon"><input type="checkbox"  data-md-icheck/></span>
                    <label>Proposition 1</label>
                    <input [(ngModel)]="proposition1.wordingP" type="text" class="md-input" required class="md-input"/>
                </div>
            </div>
```

here is the TypeScript code for adding the proposition:

```
addProp1() {
        this.proposition1 = new PropositionModel();
        this.proposition1.propStatus = false;
        this.propositionService.addProposition(this.proposition1)
            .subscribe(response=> {
                console.log(response);
                console.log(this.proposition1);
                this.proposition1 = new PropositionModel();})
    }
```

And as you can see i made it a `false` by default for the `proposition status` and I want to change it once i checked the proposition.
Here is an image how it looks for a better issue understanding.
[image]

Any help Please ?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h57j4q?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**Template:** *You can either use the native `change` event or NgModel directive's `ngModelChange`.*

```html
<input type="checkbox" (change)="onNativeChange($event)"/>
```

or

```html
<input type="checkbox" ngModel (ngModelChange)="onNgModelChange($event)"/>
```

**TS:**

```ts
onNativeChange(e) { // here e is a native event
  if(e.target.checked){
    // do something here
  }
}

onNgModelChange(e) { // here e is a boolean, true if checked, otherwise false
  if(e){
    // do something here
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that it's (change) and not (onChange). It was my silly mistake that took my a few minutes to figure out

Answer (score 16):

If you add double paranthesis to the ngModel reference you get a two-way binding to your model property. That property can then be read and used in the event handler. In my view that is the most clean approach.

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="myModel.property" (ngModelChange)="processChange()" />
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `ngModel` like

```
<input type="checkbox" [ngModel]="checkboxValue" (ngModelChange)="addProp($event)" data-md-icheck/>
```

To update the checkbox state by updating the property `checkboxValue` in your code and when the checkbox is changed by the user `addProp()` is called.

Comment: didnt work, sorry , can you clarify more according to the code above ? i'll appreciate it ..

Comment: `[ngModel]="checkboxValue"` adds the `ngModel` directrives and default `ControlValueAccessor` (and binds the value of `checkboxValue` to the checkbox). With `ngModel` we can bind to the `ngModelChange` event that is emitted every time the checkbox changes.

Comment: What Angular"'2 version are you using. There were issues with binding to some input elements in FF and IE but they were fixed recently.

Comment: it is Beta 0, and i didn't try to update it, The problem is that the `ngModel` is not considering my changes ..

Comment: You would need at least beta.16 AFAIR

Answer (score 2):

**Check Demo**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-checkbox?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html

```
  CheckBox: use change event to call the function and pass the event.

<label class="container">    
   <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="theCheckbox"  data-md-icheck 
    (change)="toggleVisibility($event)"/>
      Checkbox is <span *ngIf="marked">checked</span><span 
     *ngIf="!marked">unchecked</span>
     <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
 <div>And <b>ngModel</b> also works, it's value is <b>{{theCheckbox}}</b></div>
```