# Angular2 ngFor get only selected values

Tags: angular

I have a for loop that populates pre-defined hobbies as checkboxes.
`hobbies = ['Sport', 'Reading', 'Singing', 'Travelling', 'Movies', 'Cooking'];`

```
<label *ngFor="let hobby of chunk" #checkbox class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies" [value]="hobby" 
    [(ngModel)]="hobby.selected" (change)="populateMyHobbies(hobby)" class="mdl-checkbox__input">
    <span class="mdl-checkbox__label">{{hobby}}</span>
</label>
```

I have created an array `my_hobbies: string[]=[];` in which I want to collect only the selected values i.e. ['Sport',..]

My function that collects those values is so far:

```
populateMyHobbies(value){

    this.my_hobbies.push(value)
    console.log(this.my_hobbies)
}
```

How can I achieve this? Right now on check and uncheck the values get added even same value multiple times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Template side :

```
<label *ngFor="let hobby of chunk" #checkbox class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies" [value]="hobby" 
    [(ngModel)]="hobby.selected" (change)="populateMyHobbies(hobby,$event.target.checked)" class="mdl-checkbox__input">
    <span class="mdl-checkbox__label">{{hobby}}</span>
</label>
```

Component side :

```
selectedHobbies = [];

populateMyHobbies(value , status:boolean)
{
    if(this.selectedHobbies.indexOf(value) === -1 && status)
    {
        this.selectedHobbies.push(value);
    }
    else if(!status)
    {
        let index = this.selectedHobbies.indexOf(value);
        this.selectedHobbies.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Nitish, Great , will you please accept the answer also?

Comment: Yes sure! It's just that I have to wait for couple of minutes before I can accept it :0

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to pass the check event as an argument to `populateMyHobbies`, and then read `event.target.checked` to check whether the checkbox is checked or unchecked ([Like the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37077916/4037594)).

You can check whether the array contains a value by checking if `array.indexOf(value)` returns -1, and remove them with `array.splice(index,1)` ([As in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5767357/4037594)).